# Android - app crash due to location permission revoked from setting

Tags: android, service, crash, android-permissions, android-fusedlocation

We're using android background service for the location tracking where registering fused google api for periodic location update.
When we've to start service for location update, we ask for location permission and if user accept then we start service and register fused google api.

But now issue coming that once user accepted permission and fused location api registered for location update, later user revoked the location permission from the device setting for the app. 
Once user do this, app start crashing due to

> java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.

How to handle this situation?

Comment: Check for permission each time you request for location .

Comment: Put it inside a try catch block and issue a notification asking the user to grant the permission to continue using the app properly

Comment: Problem is that, I already have set control to fused location api periodically.

Answer (score 5):

**It's not a bug.** This is a Android 6 (Marshmallow) and above problem or we can say feature. It is because from Android Marshmallow, Google changed how users give access to the dangerous permissions (like location permission) and that they now have the ability to revoke it. In your case, what's happening is that the `savedInstanceState` value becomes invalid because your app process got killed and restarted after you revoke the permission.

One possible fix is passing null to the `onCreate()` of the activity. This is because even after your process is killed, the `savedInstanceState` still remains and is returned after you go back to the app. If you did the same thing without having the app open, it won't crash because `savedInstanceState` is null. But in case of background service, which is doing some task with the location, the app will crash as soon as you revoke the location permission from the device settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding this on MainActivity.java:

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RNBootSplash.init(this); // ⬅️ initialize the splash screen
    // Check for permissions at app launch
    if (arePermissionsGranted()) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    } else {
      super.onCreate(null);
    }
  }
  
  private boolean arePermissionsGranted() {
    // Check for the required permissions
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
      int cameraPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
      int locationPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
      int notificationPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED);

      return cameraPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
              && locationPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
              && notificationPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

So after permission are revoced and app is restared I just put `super.onCreate(null);`

Comment: Worked liked a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in your main activity and call it in your `onCreate()` method;

```
public boolean havePermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this , new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and don't forget to add thoes two permission in your mainifest.xml